# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Variable Limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

So the FToC says that if 
$G'(x) = g(x) \rightarrow \int_a^bg(s)ds = G(b) - G(a)$

Does the same thing hold if the limits a and b are functions of x?

Comment: If you mean, is $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(s)\,{\rm d}s = G(b(x)) - G(a(x))$ then yes. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: What I really need to evaluate is $\int_{0}^{h(x,y,t)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx$

Comment: If $f = f(x)$ a function of a single variable?

Comment: no, $f = f(x,y,z,t)$

Comment: We have that $\int_{x' = 0}^{x' = h} \frac{\partial f(x',y,z,t)}{\partial x'}{\rm d}x' = f(h,y,z,t) - f(0,y,z,t)$ where $h$ can be any number including a function of the coordinates. This is a special case of the [fundamental theorem of line integrals](http://faculty.up.edu/wootton/Calc3/Section17.3.pdf), also called the [gradient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem).

Comment: I literally just googled that, think it's what I need thanks very much! Tricky since the fact that it's a vector quantity doesn't pop out straight away